# Why can't debug native code on x86 instruction set Android Emulator?

Tags: android, assembly, x86, android-emulator, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to debug a android project's native code ( `.so` files )

Here's what I've done :

- setup a X86 Android Emulator using Android Studio
- push `gdbserver` into Android Emulator inside `ndk` installation folder
- running `gdbserver`, execute `adb forward tcp:xxx tcp:xxx`
- using my `gdb` and connect to `gdbserver`

So far everything works just fine. I can pause the process and resume.
But once I set a breakpoint, and resume the execution. And when it hit the breakpoint and then resume the execution, it received a lot of `SIGSEGV`.

---

Now I thought it was a bug caused by `gdbserver` and `gdb`.

And then I turn to use IDA 7.5, and push `android_x86_server` into Android Emulator, setup everything and connect to it.

Same thing happens, before I set a breakpoint, everything works fine, but once I set a breakpoint and wait till execution to hit the breakpoint and then resume execution, It keeps received `SIGSEGV` at the same position ( causing by a instruction trying to access memory of `0x00` )

---

Another wired thing is even if I don't set a breakpoint, just randomly click pause and resume, I found that the `EIP` always stop at the same position whenever I click pause.

---

Comment: When you randomly click pause, is your program / app always in a sleep (e.g. `select` or `poll` system call), waiting for input?  If so, it wouldn't be super surprising to see the same EIP repeatedly, probably the EIP of the `sysenter` in the VDSO if you're actually using obsolete 32-bit code, instead of 64-bit code where the libc wrapper for each system call can inline a `syscall`.  IDK about the other effects you're seeing; I don't do Android development, and it's also not a [mcve].  Although you're implying spurious SIGSEGV would happen with any project?

Comment: Very much what you said, it did stop at `vdso` and the stack did contain address of `epoll` related function. But it just a simple demo project that I create using unity with il2cpp backend. And I don't see where I ever used `epoll`. And I can't figure out why I received that lot `SIGSEGV` after resume from a breakpoint.  It certainly not some anti-debug technology. And I trying that on quite some app on that x86 emulator, It all show the same result. ( keeps receiving `SIGXXX` after resume from a breakpoint )

Comment: It would be helpful if someone know what a emulator can emulate and what can't.  I myself think it has something to do with `X86` arch emulator I use, but because `ARM` arch emulator works real slow on my PC, I wouldn't be able to work if it is because the instruction set or not. Also because I don't have a android device with root authority, I can't work on real device either